# Trace Entity Framework 4.0 : Extra queries for foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

In the following example, we insert an entity called taskinstance to our context. we have a foreign key FK_Contract that we set at 2.

```
entity.FK_Contract = 2;
context.TaskInstances.AddObject(entity);
```

The query generated by entity framework is a simple insert. (everything is fine)

However, the following query works differently.

```
int contractId = context.Contracts.Where((T) => T.Name == contractName).Single().Id;
entity.FK_Contract = contractId;
context.TaskInstances.AddObject(entity);
```

In the trace created by entity framework we see without surprise the query selecting the Id according a contractName but we also see an extra request looking like:

```
select id,... from [TaskInstances] WHERE [Extent1].[FK_Task] = @contractId
```

This extra query leads to many problems, especially when we work with a foreign table with millions of record. The network goes down!

Therefore we 'd like to **figure out the purpose** of this extra query **and the way to make it disappear**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the extra query is populating a collection of tasks on the returned `Contract` object. Try projecting just the column you want:

```
int contractId = context.Contracts
   .Where(T => T.Name == contractName)
   .Select(T => T.Id)
   .Single();
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, Your reply fixed my issue ! :)